# Blender changes keyboard layout when being used till reboot

Tags: shortcut, keymap

This is something i just encountered while using Blender with Windows

Whenever i use Blender my keyboard layout changes from german to english or something similar. This is rather annoying because most of the special characters are in different places and the Z key is swapped with Y.

This isnt a problem that then only occurs in Blender. Infact, i am even writing this with the wrong keyboard layout right now.

I am very confused as to what could cause this and why it happens and most imoprtantly, how to fix it?

Comment: Most likely you press `Alt`+`Shift` by accident, which is a *Windows* shortcut to switch the language (not related to blender): https://superuser.com/questions/698037/can-i-disable-the-altshift-shortcut-to-change-language-in-windows-8-1-or-win

Comment: thank you, will look into it (great how windows just doesn't give you an update at all when your keymap changes -.-). but yeah. apparetnyl ctrl + shift and alt + shift are hotkeys to switch the keyboard language and those are very present hotkeys in blender altough i wasnt able to reproduce the issue rn. will see if it fixed it

Comment: @p2or Could you post that as a answer? Please ping me in the comments if you do for an upvote

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i posted an ansewr ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem wasn't related to Blender per se but more an action that you frequently do in Blender. When you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> under Windows operating systems it will change your keyboards layout.

You can turn this off by toggling a setting in windows. It is explained in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/698037/can-i-disable-the-altshift-shortcut-to-change-language-in-windows-8-1-or-win :

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `Advanced keyboard settings` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   [image: Windows Search for 'Advanced Keyboard Settings']
2. **Input language hot keys** (left)
   [image: Select 'Input language hot keys']
3. **Change Key Sequence...** (for "Between input languages")
   [image: Select "Advanced Key Settings" tab, and press "Change Key Sequence"]
4. **Set to "Not Assigned"** 
   [image]